# Gstreamer code equivalent for gst-launch command

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

I use following command to create a pipeline from cmd.

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=c:\\song.mp3  ! mad ! audioconvert ! directsoundsink
```

how to code the above command into a program?

Answer (score 1):

by "program" is guess you mean a file that you can run.

you can simply put the gst-launch stanza into a script-file, and run that script-file.

the following example uses [bash](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne-again_shell) syntax (save it in a file *playmad*, make the file executable and run `playmad /path/to/song.mp3`)

```
#!/bin/sh
SOURCE=$1
test -e "${SOURCE}" && \
gst-launch -v filesrc location="${SOURCE}" \
              ! mad \
              ! audioconvert \
              ! directsoundsink
```

on w32, you can create a `.bat` file that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

All gstreamer modules have test/examples directories which you can also look at [the git browser](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/tests/examples). To implement the above gst-launch invocation as a programm you need to pick the languag (e.g. c or python) and implement that using the gst API. Don't expect that someone does that for you here though.